# htaccess - add www & remove index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have my current htaccess as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=$1 [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

when I go to to abc.com, it redirects properly to www.abc.com which is good.

However, if I go to abc.com/about - it redirects to abc.com/index.php?load=about, I want it to redirect to www.abc.com/about.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?load=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: You need to test this in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

To force WWW:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

To remove index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```